# How to fetch items one by one from firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6

How can I add only one element to the page that I have added? Now, every time I add a bank, the entire database is pulled out and those banks that have already been added are drawn again.

```js
const sendBankData = () => {
  set(ref(database, "banks/" + bankName.value), {
    bankName: bankName.value,
    interestRate: interestRate.value,
    maximumLoan: maximumLoan.value,
    minimumDownPayment: minimumDownPayment.value,
    loanTerm: loanTerm.value,
  })
    .then(() => {
      successfulPopUp();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // errorPopUp();
    });
};
```

```js
const getBanksFunc = () => {
  const bankRef = ref(database, "banks/");
  onValue(bankRef, (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    displayBanks(data);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used Firebase in a long time but if I remember correctly you'd pass the ID of the bank into the ref
`(const bankRef = ref(database, "banks/ID-OF-THE-BANK");`

or you could sort and limit by create date.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above mentioned.
You need to pass the ID to get the document you just inserted.

So for that, you have two options:

One is to set a custom document Id and get the id you just inserted.
Or get the doc id with the reference:

But for Firestore realtime

```
const sendBankData = () => {
  set(ref(database, "banks/" + bankName.value), {
    bankName: bankName.value,
    interestRate: interestRate.value,
    maximumLoan: maximumLoan.value,
    minimumDownPayment: minimumDownPayment.value,
    loanTerm: loanTerm.value,
  }).catch((error) => {
      // errorPopUp();
    });
};

/* You should be able to get the key from the just inserted document using this: */
const sendBankData_key = sendBankData.key
```

/* Then you should be able to push it, also accordingly the doc, you can insert a blank document, get the key and then update it. Also, you can use transactions to update several times inserted documents and avoid inconsistency.  */

```
const getBanksFunc = () => {
const bankRef = ref(database, "banks/${sendBankData_key}");
onValue(bankRef, (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  displayBanks(data);
 });
```

};

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What is docRef ? Now then() doesn't work

Comment: Try that way, the doc ref,  basically when you are sending a request to firebase API it will send you a response that you can store in the docRef , you can see more details here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-8_8

Comment: I missed the parenthesis,  when you are doing this "()" is just like creating a new function but when you are using a promise you get the response in the then.

Comment: i don't use firestore in app. I am using Realtime DB

Comment: On web? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web-version-8_4 thats cool then you already have the reference but would be a little different. I will edit the answe